# How to show events for LoggedIn User only using Full Calendar and Vue js?

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar

I'm developing a Job Search app where an employer and candidate can create interviews. I'm using Laravel for my back-end and Vue js for my front-end. I'm trying to display all of the "events" in the Calendar. For some reason in my EmployerInterviewController.php I'm able to display all of the records in the table and display them in the Calendar, but when I add a where clause and try to display only the events that belong to the Logged In User, the events no longer display in the Calendar. This might be a Vue Object/Array issue, but I'm new to Vue js, so I'm not sure what the issue is. Here is my code:

Displays all the events on the Calendar from the Interviews Table:

```
public function index()
    {
        $interviews = Interview::all();

        return response()->json($interviews, 200);

    }
```

Doesn't display any events on the Calendar.

```
public function index()
    {
        $interviews = Interview::all()->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);

        return response()->json($interviews, 200);

    }
```

I've attached two screenshots where I console logged the data above, so you can see what is being returned.
enter image description here
[image]

[image]

Comment: In your second example it seems to return an object instead of an array. fullcalendar expects an array. You need to arrange your server-side code so that it always returns an array, even if the array only has one event in it.